# PHP DB Connection questions

Tags: php

I am getting the error:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/mjcrawle/public_html/home/index.php on line 23

Line 23 turns out to be `$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);` but I am thinking the error is further up but I am having trouble finding it.

The actual code that I am using to connect to the DB is (I do understand there is a redundancy if the database cannot connect):

Any help would be wonderful and a reason for the error would be awesome!

```
/*Connect To DB*/
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd)
        or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error()); //connect to server
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $database)
        or die("Error: Could not connect to the database: " . mysql_error());

    /*Check for Connection*/
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        /*Display Error message if fails*/
        echo 'Error, could not connect to the database please try again later.';
    exit();
    }

/* Query for states */
$query = "SELECT StateAbbreviation, StateName, FROM USState ORDER BY StateName";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra comma before the `FROM` in `query = "SELECT StateAbbreviation, StateName, FROM USState ORDER BY StateName";`, you may be getting an error and not having a result when you execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

If the query fails, mysqli_query returns boolean `false`

After `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);`, you should test the return value before continuing:

```
if ( ! $result){
   $error = mysqli_error($conn);
   //do something with the error message
}
```

See EmCo's answer for why your query is failing.

Comment: better to check `if ($result !== FALSE)`.  If for whatever reason mysqli_query could return a 0, your test would indicate it failed, though only an actual boolean FALSE indicates that.

Answer (score 0):

`<?php 
   $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dbname') or die ("Connection Failed");
 ?>`

This is the simple method of DB Connection